# What weights represent in Jaegar dependencies DAG view?

Tags: trace, opentracing, jaeger

I'm unable to find what these edge weights(red circle) represent inside my DAG view.
[image]

Any of you know what they try to represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It represents the number of requests made from one service to other.